# Filling geometry_msgs/Pose2D[] message

Tags: ros, c++, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i am failing to fill a ros message and google serves me no good.

The message is of the following format

```
Header header
string child_frame_id
geometry_msgs/Pose2D[] pose
```

Maybe i lack the needes C++ skills, but i just dont understand the automatic created class for this message. How do i fill Pose2D elements to a new message?

I tried something like the following without success:

```
pedestrianSim::pedestrians msg;
geometry_msgs::Pose2D_ singlePos;
singlePos.x = x;
singlePos.y = y;
singlePos.theta = omega;
msg.pose.push_back( singlePos );
```

Thank you for your help!

Regards,
Manuel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36724/filling-geometry_msgs/pose2d%5B%5D-message/) by [mapa17](https://answers.ros.org/users/2363/mapa17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would help to see your error messages.

Looking at what information you did provide, I suggest leaving off the trailing '`_'` from the message type name:

```
geometry_msgs::Pose2D singlePos;
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3